# I need to send sms OTP and verify OTP by Firebase APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api

I create an app by using the ruby on rails framework only API. In the app, there is an authentic by sending an OTP code to the phone. So I need to use a Firebase service phone to authenticate. The issue is there are no APIs to send OTP code and verification code and skip reCAPTCHA in Firebase services. Does anyone know about anything help me, please?